# how to style steep oval shape button

Tags: nativescript

I'm trying to design a label or button with some text inside it. I know how to give border radius and make it oval but I need an eye shape wide button or label like exactly below.

[image: oval eye shape button]

i follwed this link https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_shapes_oval with no results like rectangle shapes with round border button below

[image: failed]

then,I tried the below code but only the corners are getting rounded.

```
.boc1 {
    border-width: 1;
    border-radius: 100;
    padding: -2px;
    margin: 10% 0 0 0;
    padding: 10% 0 10% 0;
    height:100%;
    width:85%;
}
```

I hope you are clear about the problem..!

Answer (score 0):

Change border-radius as `border-radius:50px;`

Comment: i dont what link is this. a box with rounded corner. please read the question properly before answering.

Answer (score 0):

Use [clip-path](https://bennettfeely.com/clippy/)

**XML**

```
<GridLayout>
    <StackLayout class="oval"></StackLayout>
    <Label class="h2" text="Some text" color="white" verticalAlignment="center"
        horizontalAlignment="center"></Label>
</GridLayout>
```

**CSS**

```
.oval {
    width: 85%;
    background-color: red;
    clip-path: ellipse(50% 15% at 50% 50%);
}
```